# How to set origin to joint location?

Tags: origin

I have cut a hand into pieces. Now I wish to set the origin of each piece to the bone joint of the given body part as seen on the picture. I know I can place the cursor on the joint and set the origin this way, but is there a way to do it with a script. It would save me a lot of work!  [image]

Comment: In Edit mode (of the armature) select the joint and hit shift+s then select "Cursor to selected". In Object mode select the mesh then hit ctrl+shift+alt+c and select "Origin to 3D cursor".

Comment: It still puts the cursor at the center of the bone not at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

In edit mode, select the joint (not the bone), SHIFT+S > cursor to selected, then in Object mode, go to the object menu Object > Set Origin > Origin to 3D cursor.

Just note, the ctrl+shift+alt+c hotkey has been changed in blender version 2.8

Comment: Selecting the joint is want I would like to do using a script because I have almost 50 joints. Any idea how to go about this?